# read the text file in azure storage blob line by line using python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need to read text files from blob storage line by line and perform some operations and get a specific line to data frame. I have tried various ways to read file line by line. Is there any way to read a text file from blob line-line and perform operations and output specific line just like readlines() while data is in local storage?

```
candidate_resume = 'candidateresumetext'
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='nam', account_key='key')
generator2 = block_blob_service.list_blobs(candidate_resume)
#for blob in generator2:
   #print(blob.name)
for blob in generator2:
    blob2 = block_blob_service.get_blob_to_text(candidate_resume,blob.name)
    #print(blob2)

    #blob_url=block_blob_service.make_blob_url(candidate_resume, blob.name)
    #print(blob_url)

    #blob3 = block_blob_service.get_blob_to_stream(candidate_resume,blob.name,range)
    blob3 = blob2.split('.')
    with open(blob.name,encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in blob3:      
            if any(p in years_list for p in line ):
                if any(p in months_list for p in line):    
                    print(line)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `get_blob_to_text` is the right way, and you can follow the sample code below(you can make some changes if it does not meet your need). And you cannot use `with open() as file` since no real file is there.

```
#read the content of the blob(assume it's a .txt file)
str1 = block_blob_service.get_blob_to_text(container_name,blob_name)

#split the string str1 with newline.
arr1 = str1.content.splitlines()

#read the one line each time.
for a1 in arr1:
    print(a1)
```

Comment: Hello, if the answer works, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: yea it worked for me . there are like 10000 text files in blob. can we get the file name assigned to each line i retreived ?

Comment: do you mean that there are some files like a.txt,b.txt, and when you get each line from a.txt or b.txt, add the file name(a.txt or b.txt) to each line?

Comment: If it's the case I mentioned, you can just directly add the blob name in the print(), like print(blob_name+":"+a1)