# Azure python function. Read Blob line by line

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

using azure python function, I am able to read the full file at once.
([Read data from Azure blob storage in Azure Function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64776039/read-data-from-azure-blob-storage-in-azure-function-in-python))

```
blob_client = BlobClient.from_blob_url("your Blob SAS URL here")
download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
logging.info('=========below is content of test1')
logging.info(download_stream.readall())
logging.info('=========above is content of test1')
```

Is there a way you can read the blob file line by line?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this code to read blob file line by line

```
str1 = block_blob_service.get_blob_to_text(container_name,blob_name)

#split the string str1 with newline.
arr1 = str1.content.splitlines()

#read the one line each time.
for a1 in arr1:
    print(a1)
```

for more refere you may check with this link

[read the text file in azure storage blob line by line using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55968716/read-the-text-file-in-azure-storage-blob-line-by-line-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here my code to access with the SAS token:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='<account_name>', account_key=None,sas_token ='<sas_token>')
str1 = block_blob_service.get_blob_to_text('<container_name>','<blob_name>')
arr1 = str1.content.splitlines()
#read the one line each time.
for a1 in arr1:
    print(a1)
```

As a pitfall, the SAS token starts without the ? symbol. The SAS token shall start with something like: 'sv='